# Django heroku : Unable to deploy application (ModuleNotFoundError)

Tags: django, heroku

When I am deploying my Django application on Heroku, the application crash and Heroku's logs notify me about this error :

```
2020-12-07T12:55:55.982458+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'WebSite'
```

The thing is, `WebSite` is not a Python module, but a folder in my Django application (`Achievement Comparer` being my main application name).

- `AchievementComparer/`

  - `AchievementComparer/` ← My Django project
  - `static/`
  - `staticfiles/`
  - `WebSite/` ← A Django app
  - `__init__.py`
  - `manage.py`
  - `wsgi.py`
- `Procfile`
- `requirements.txt`
- `runtime.txt`

Of course, if I start my application locally, everything works just fine (running `py manage.py runserver` on Windows, as `gunicorn` is only available on unix).

Comment: "The thing is, WebSite is not a python module, but a folder in my Django application"—folders and Python modules are related concepts.

Comment: What is in your `WebSite/` folder? Is that your Django project directory? Or an app? What is in your `Procfile`?

Comment: @Chris You can find my project [here](https://github.com/Strapontin/AchievementComparer).

I have made several changes trying to get around my problem, so now my `Procfile` may have changed from when I posted this question. By trying to edit the `Procfile` and `wsgi.py`, I end up with 3 differents `ModuleNameError`, referring to `wsgi`, `settings` or `WebSite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current issue is that you have an extra directory layer:

- `AchievementComparer/` ← This shouldn't be here

  - `AchievementComparer/`
  - `WebSite/`
  - `manage.py`
  - …
- `Procfile`
- `requirements.txt`
- `runtime.txt`

Move everything that's currently in the top-level `AchievementComparer/` directory up a level and delete the now-empty old `AchievementComparer/` directory:

- `AchievementComparer/`

  - `asgi.py`
  - `settings.py`
  - `wsgi.py`
- `WebSite/`
- `manage.py`
- `Procfile`
- `requirements.txt`
- `runtime.txt`

A few other issues that are likely to bite you next:

- The only `wsgi.py` file you should need is the one that's currently in your `AchievementComparer/` project directory, beside your `settings.py`. Delete the other one.
- Your `Procfile` is hard-coding a port. You'll need to bind to whatever port Heroku assigns you via the `PORT` environment variable.
- You don't need `--pythonpath` in your `Procfile`, but you should update the module to use the full module name `AchievementComparer.wsgi`.

All in all, try changing your `Procfile` to something like this:

```
web: gunicorn AchievementComparer.wsgi:application --bind=0.0.0.0:$PORT --log-file -
```

Comment: Thanks. A lot. following your tips and copying this code almost made the entire trick, I just had to make a minor modification to my wsgi file (adding `AchievementComparer.` before `settings` so the settings would be found correctly). I've spend a lot of time looking around on various topics so I would understand my mistake, but it seems like no one had something similar.

Would you care explaining why I had to bring those folders up ? The website was already working great locally, so I don't understand why it wouldn't otherwise...

Comment: I'm glad this helped! Heroku depends on being able to run everything from the top-level directory. It's probably _possible_ to get some variation of your old structure working by jumping through a bunch of hoops, but the simplest solution by far is to just put everything in the root directory like this.